# How do i include white space in my Caesar Cipher program in C++?

Tags: c++, encryption, software-design, caesar-cipher

Ok so last time I asked for help on this program because I could not convert characters to DEC and add to it. I finally got it to work thanks to some advice that was given, it's almost complete.

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
char word[128];
int x = 0;
int v;
int shift;
int sv;

cin >> shift;
cin >> word;



while (word[x] !='\0')    // While the string isn't at the end... 
{

    v = int(word[x]);


    sv = v + shift;


    x++;

   cout<< static_cast<char>(sv);

}



return 0;
}
```

However i have no idea how to get it to accept white spaces using

```
isspace
```

Can yall help me?

Comment: Read the text using std::getline.

Comment: Search your favorite C++ reference for "noskipws".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that won't help with a `char` array as argument to `operator>>()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getline` in string might be your friend in this case. here is your code but fixed up to use that.

```
#include <string>

int rotMain()
{
  //char word[128];
  string word;
  int x = 0;
  int v;
  int shift;
  int sv;

  cin >> shift;
  getline(cin, word);

  while (word[x] != '\0')    // While the string isn't at the end... 
  {
    v = int(word[x]);
    sv = v + shift;
    x++;
    cout << static_cast<char>(sv);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

you're doing a few other things that are a little strange here, like you're not taking the modulus of any of your characters so, for example 'Z' rotated by 1 will be '[', but this might be by design? Also suggest iterating over the string using standard iterators, but if you're just learning don't worry about any of that for now!

Comment: Thank you so much, yeah this is way better. I'll look over my code, have not had much practice

Comment: glad to help! keep posting if you have questions